# Yii2: why "use Yii" the yii is capitalized

Tags: php, yii2

when use Yii helper class, why the using namespace statment is "use Yii;" ,the yii is capitalized,while the namespace is definited "namespace yii;".

Comment: Namespaces are case-insensitive (NOT case sensitive) just like class names and function names.

Comment: This is true but remember that Yii autoloader uses namespaces for autoloading classes and the file names are case-sensitive on most non-Windows environments - that is why it's better to keep proper character case in namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Yii` (as in `use Yii;`) is the name of the class and since Yii 2 follows Basic Coding Standard [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) (among the others) it starts with capital letter.

`namespace yii;` is defined for class `BaseYii` which `Yii` extends.

Class `Yii` itself is not defined within any namespace and that is why you can use it with just `use Yii;`

Notice that `yii` in `use Yii;` is not the same as the one in `namespace yii;` - first one is a class, second is a namespace.